# Listbox with checkboxes Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want to make listbox with checkboxes in it. I made only listbox for now, but I do not know how to put checkboxes in it. And then I want to create a button , so that I can print all selected items. Can you please help me?

```
from tkinter import *

myApp=Tk()

LB=Listbox(myApp,selectmode=EXTENDED)
LB.grid(row=1,column=1)
LB.insert(1,"Option 1")
LB.insert(2,"Option 2")
LB.insert(3,"Option 3")

myApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: It  is not recommended you use `from tkinter import *`. This can cause problems.

Comment: What should I use?

Comment: `import tkinter` is one way.  Then you would need to use `tkinter.insert()`. Or to save yourself from typing `tkinter` each time you can define it as something else.  For example `import tkinter as tk`.  This would be `tk.insert()`

Comment: you cannot put checkboxes in the listbox. Selection is shown via highlighting.

Comment: Why do you want them in a Listbox? If you want a scrolled window you can put your Checkboxes in a ScrolledText widget.

Comment: [`tkinter.tix.CheckList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.tix.html#tkinter.tix.CheckList) exists, at least through Python 3.6.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727332/python-tkinter-create-checkbox-list-from-listbox) your question?

Answer (score 0):

The following would give you the check buttons
but not in a listbox. Listbox can only contain text.

```
from tkinter import Tk, IntVar, Checkbutton, Button, W


def print_button_callback():
    global state
    for i in range(3):
        if state[i][1].get():
            print(state[i][0])

myApp=Tk()
state = [("Option {0}".format(i+1),IntVar()) for i in range(3)]

for i in range(3):
    Checkbutton(myApp, text=state[i][0], variable=state[i][1]).grid(row=i, sticky=W)

Button(myApp, text="Print", command=print_button_callback).grid(row=3, sticky=W)


myApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: i need to make checkboxes to be into listbox

Comment: You cannot insert checkboxes into a listbox. A listbox can only contain text.

Comment: If you need a listbox you can insert a tick character in the text when selected and remove it when deselected but it sounds like reinventing the wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a way to solve this for a while now, but finally got an answer.
Since using checkbox in a list box has been discontinued then we can manipulate our way inside by using a Unicode character.

Thus, your code will be like this

```
from tkinter import *

myApp=Tk()

LB=Listbox(myApp,selectmode=EXTENDED)
LB.grid(row=1,column=1)

''' assigning a variable check to the Unicode Character for checkbox
Then call the variable check in each insert command
Make sure you concatenate it with a + else it send it to the next line 
'''

check = u"\u2705 "
LB.insert(1, check + "Option 1")
LB.insert(2, check + "Option 2")
LB.insert(3, check + "Option 3")

myApp.mainloop()
```

`