# Python (Tkinter)- Create Checkbox list from listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I want to create a checkbox list for every listbox item. So, I have a listbox created with 4 different items, "one", "two", "three", "four". I want to have a list of corresponding checkbox items for each of the listbox entries. When I click on a listbox entry, it should have a list of checkboxes on the right and when I click on a different listbox entry it should have a list of checkboxes that would be independent of the other listbox items. All checkbox lists are independent of each other, meaning you can check 4 checkboxes when the first listbox entry is selected, but when I select the second listbox entry it should show 0 things checked (because they are independent).

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


master = tkinter.Tk()
master.geometry("750x500")

listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.place(x=3,y=0)


for item in ["one", "two", "three", "four"]:
    listbox.insert(END, item)

enable = {'button 1','button 2', 'button 3'}

def onselect(evt):
    # Note here that Tkinter passes an event object to onselect()
    w = evt.widget
    x=0
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
    print ('You selected item %d: "%s"' % (index, value))
    for item in enable:
        checkboxes = Checkbutton(master, text=item, variable=item)
        checkboxes.place(x=300,y=0+x)
        x+=50

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)

print(enable)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question and I have been working on it for 30 min. There are of course several ways, here the probably shortest and most dynamic:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter
from tkinter import *

master = tkinter.Tk()
master.geometry("750x500")

listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.place(x=3,y=0)

enable = ['button 1', 'button 2', 'button 3']
list_for_listbox = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

for item in list_for_listbox:
    listbox.insert(END, item)
    for y in enable:
        globals()["var{}{}".format(item, y)] = BooleanVar()
        globals()["checkbox{}{}".format(item, y)] = Checkbutton(master, text=y, variable=globals()["var{}{}".format(item, y)])

def onselect(evt):
    # Note here that Tkinter passes an event object to onselect()
    w = evt.widget
    x=0
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
    print ('You selected item %d: "%s"' % (index, value))

    for y in enable:
        for item in list_for_listbox:
            globals()["checkbox{}{}".format(item, y)].place_forget()
        globals()["checkbox{}{}".format(value, y)].place(x=300,y=0+x)
        x+=50

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)

print(enable)

mainloop()
```

You access the vars by `globals()["var{}{}".format(item, y)]`

example:

```
for item in list_for_listbox:
    for y in enable:
        print(item + " [" + y + "] " + str(globals()["var{}{}".format(item, y)].get()))
```

Comment: Can you show me how to add a scroll bar to a list of atleast 20 checkboxes per listbox item? I want the checkboxes to be within some sort of text widget that can be scrolled.

Comment: So should the left list be scrolled or the accumulation of check buttons on the right?

Comment: I have a answer to qour scrollbar question, but could you open a new page for your question so i can answer it and not have to comment? You can post the link to your new question as a comment right here. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760572/scrollable-checkbuttons-from-selected-listbox-items here is the new post for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your program needs to remember some state.

You can pass a `BooleanVar()` to a `Checkbutton` widget, and the widget will keep that `BooleanVar` up to date.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter
from tkinter import *

master = tkinter.Tk()
master.geometry("750x500")

listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.place(x=3, y=0)

gui_state = {
    "one": {
        'button 1': BooleanVar(),
        'button 2': BooleanVar(),
        'button 3': BooleanVar(),
    },
    "two": {
        'button 1': BooleanVar(),
        'button 2': BooleanVar(),
        'button 3': BooleanVar(),
    },
    "three": {
        'button 1': BooleanVar(),
        'button 2': BooleanVar(),
        'button 3': BooleanVar(),
    },
    "four": {
        'button 1': BooleanVar(),
        'button 2': BooleanVar(),
        'button 3': BooleanVar(),
    },
}

for item in gui_state.keys():
    listbox.insert(END, item)


def bind_checkboxen(master, category):
    # render checkboxes for category. Mutate category when checkboxes are toggled.
    global checkboxes

    # delete old checkboxes
    for checkbox in checkboxes:
        checkbox.destroy()
    checkboxes = []

    x = 0

    # create new ones based on category fields
    for key in category.keys():
        checkbox = Checkbutton(master, text=key, variable=category[key])
        checkbox.place(x=300, y=0 + x)
        checkboxes.append(checkbox)
        x += 50


checkboxes = []


def onselect(evt):
    # Note here that Tkinter passes an event object to onselect()
    w = evt.widget
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
    print('You selected item %d: "%s"' % (index, value))
    bind_checkboxen(master, gui_state[value])


listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)

mainloop()
```